# Laravel5.4 Error 'Swift_TransportException' occurred when sending mail via smtp on amazon

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, smtp, laravel-5.4

I set the environment variables correctly.
Also set the ses 'key', 'secret' and 'region', `MAIL_USERNAME`, and `MAIL_PASSWORD` correctly.

the following is laravel error:
[image: Laravel Image]

And the following is my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME= 'My user name'
MAIL_PASSWORD= 'My password'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

And the following is sending email code:

```
    Mail::to('target@yahoo.com')->send(new Product('sending content'));
```

Also, I added target email address on amazon.

Explain me why this error occurred.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you get the `MAIL_USERNAME` and `MAIL_PASSWORD`?

Comment: Yeah. I get them and set correctly. Can you tell me getting method of them? Then I can follow your way and will reset the values.

Comment: If you cannot tell how you got the credentials, how do I know if your setup was configured correctly or not?

Comment: Just think I don't know anything and explain me how can I get credentials. Tell me step by step If you can. Because I followed instructions from google but I think that's not correct way. So I can't know current credentials are correct. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved the problem. The error occurred from mail.php which contains information of mail settings.

If you met this error, check the followings:

1. Check the variables in .env and mail.php both.
   Don't redefine the variables in mail.php that defined in .env file.
2. Check that you used `env()` function correctly.
   I just got error in `env()` function.
   You should use the function like the followings:

   'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'your-username');

   The first parameter is key and the next parameter is default value.

Hope that this will help you.